# Deleting a python class instance inside a django view

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a class definition as follows

```
class DashBoard(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.ASC = 'asc'
    self.DESC = 'desc'
    self.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 10


  def delete_dashboard(self, dashboard_name):
    '''
    function definition here
    '''

  def create_dashboard(self, members_and_scores):
    '''
    This will create the dashboard
    '''

  def update_dashboard(self, members_and_scores):
    '''
    This will update the dashboard
    '''
```

Now inside a django view, I instantiate the above class and update the dashboard, a minimal representation can be shown as follows :

```
def some_django_view(request):
    dashboard_instance = DashBoard()
    member = mobj.shared_by
    dashboard_instance.update_member_data(member, **options)

   '''
   rest stuff here 
   '''
```

Now what do I do with the dashboard_instance?

Do I need to specifically delete the instance?

Please think from the memory leak/garbage collection POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't know from what background you came (what languages you used before), but python uses garbage collection.

You (generally) don't have to worry about leakage. Once your intance is out of scope and unreachable, it becames a candidate for garbage collection, and the memory assigned to it will be freed eventually.

Here are some relevant links:

- [Python Garbage Collection](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection)
- [`gc` module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html)
- [Details on Garbage Collection for Python](http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/)

Comment: No, Python uses reference counting. Garbage collection is only used to clear up cyclical references.

Comment: @DanielRoseman feel free to correct the answer or make an answer yourself then. Even if the process is different, I think the concept is pretty similar, but I might be wrong.